# Derive DFT of $x((n+1)/2)$

Tags: dft, homework

> If $X(k)$ is the $N$-point DFT of $x(n)$, and 
>   $y(n)= x\left(\frac {n+1}{2}\right)$ for odd $n$, and $0$ for even $n$.
>
> What is the $2N$ point DFT of $y(n)$ in terms of $X(k)$?

So far, I've noticed that $y(2n+1)=x(n+1)$, but I'm not sure what to do with that information in terms of the DFT summation. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Hint: Write down _explicitly_, using numbers and not symbols such as $n$ or $N$, the six elements of the sequence $y$ for the case $N=3$. You can have $y$ and $x$ in your answer but no _symbol_ $n$ or $N$. Then write down the six-point DFT of $y$, (no summation signs $\displaystyle\Sigma$ allowed) and replace each $y$ by the corresponding value from your first answer. You should be having six equations here. Then write the 3-point DFT of  $x$ using the same rules. Finally stare very hard at the results.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, I got the answer, but I want to know how to derive it directly.

Comment: @S'Danc: Dilip's suggestion was supposed to help you derive it yourself. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow a signal block diagram based solution for this problem.

First as suggested in the comments, it's very helpful to investigate a few values of $y[n]$ and $x[n]$ for some $n$ :

$$
\begin{align}
y[0] &= 0 ~~~,~~~ y[1] = x[1] \\ 
y[2] &= 0 ~~~,~~~ y[3] = x[2] \\
y[4] &= 0 ~~~,~~~ y[5] = x[3] \\
y[6] &= 0 ~~~,~~~ y[7] = x[4] \\
\end{align}
$$

with some experience, or by a direct investigation of this above sequence it can be seen that the system that produce $y[n]$ from $x[n]$ is the folowing :

$$ x[n] \longrightarrow \boxed{ \uparrow 2} \longrightarrow  w[n] \longrightarrow \boxed{ z^1} \longrightarrow y[n]$$

where the up arrow indicates an expansion by $2$ and the $z^1$ indicates a left shift (advance) by one sample.

Write down the DTFT relations between those signals $x[n]$,$w[n]$ and $y[n]$ :

$$
\begin{align}
W(\omega) &= X(2\omega) \\ 
Y(\omega) &= e^{j\omega} W(\omega) \\ \\
Y(\omega) &= e^{j\omega} X(2\omega) \\
\end{align}
$$

And relate $2N$ point DFT $Y[k]$ of $y[n]$ to $N$ point DFT $X[k]$ of $x[n]$.

$$
\begin{align}
Y[k] &= Y(\omega_k) = Y(\frac{2\pi}{2N} k) &, ~~ k=0,1,...,2N-1\\
Y[k] &= e^{j \frac{2\pi}{2N} k} X(\frac{2\pi}{N} k) &, ~~ k = 0,1,...,2N-1\\
Y[k] &= e^{j \frac{\pi}{N} k} X[k] &, ~~ k = 0,1,...,2N-1
\end{align}
$$

It can be seen that the length $2N$ DFT sequence $Y[k]$ consists of two fold replica of length $N$ DFT sequence $X[k]$ weighted by $e^{j \frac{\pi}{N} k}$. Note that $X[k]$ is periodic in $k$ by $N$, hence repeats twice during $k = 0,1,...,2N-1$.